# In pig how do i write a date, like in sql we write where date =''

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig scripting but good with SQL. I wanted the pig equivalent for this SQL line :
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Date='2008-11-11'.
Basically I want to load data for one id or date how do I do that?

Comment: what is the 'where' equivalent of SQL is Pig?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked, used FILTER in pig, and got the desired results.

```
`ivr_src = LOAD '/raw/prod/...;
 info =  foreach ivr_src generate timeEpochMillisUTC as time, cSId as id;
 Filter_table= FILTER info BY id == '700000';
 sorted_filter_table = Order Filter_table BY $1;
 store sorted_filter_table into 'sorted_filter_table1' USING PigStorage('\t', '- 
 schema');`
```